# cp: cannot stat ‘/mnt/ask78b30/TEST_FILE’: Remote I/O error

Tags: python, linux, shell, mount, cp

I am copying a file to nfs mounted dir. When I run the following command manually, the file is successfully copied

sudo cp TEST_FILE  /mnt/ask78b30

However, when I use the same command in a python script, I get the following error,

running cmd = sudo cp TEST_FILE  /mnt/ask78b30

cp: cannot stat ‘/mnt/ask78b30/TEST_FILE’: Remote I/O error

Below is the code:

```
    cmd = "sudo cp "+file_name_arg+" "+ mount_pt_arg

    print "cmd = ", cmd

    os.system(cmd)
```

---

Note: Earlier command used to fail since â speacial char was added. I changed outty to UTF-8 and that got resolved
cp: cannot stat â/mnt/askdab3c/TEST_FILEâ: Remote I/O error

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use pythons shutil to copy files instead of calling cp

```
from shutil import copyfile

copyfile(src, dst)
```

Comment: I tried the suggested methor earlier. That caused script to terminate

  File "/home/root1/test-fifaa/test-common/tests/testautomation/Lib_Support_Functions.py", line 154, in Write_Test_File_To_Share

    shutil.copy2(file_name_arg, mount_pt_arg)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 130, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 83, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:

IOError: [Errno 121] Remote I/O error: '/mnt/ask5f0f0/TEST_FILE'